# Weird Midnight Commander look in tmux

Tags: midnight-commander

How to fix this mc look in tmux session?

[image]

This is how mc looks without tmux

[image]

I have `export TERM=xterm-256color` in .bash_profile

`set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in .tmux.conf file

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` tell you inside `tmux`, before launching `mc`? It needs to be something `screen`-related. Perhaps you launch login shells inside `tmux`, and hence your `.bash_profile` (or maybe `.bashrc`) reverts it to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: What you tried `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` actually solved the problem at my end, though I only had the issue within the mc viewer and editor. For anyone landing here, you also need to restart mc and tmux before trying this solution.